# How do I add multiple objects as a single asset to the Asset Browser?

Tags: asset-browser

I am missing something really stupid here.

New blender file. Add a cube. Add a cylinder. Move them and make the cube the parent.
I now have a shape that I would like to add to an asset library.

However whenever I try to 'mark as asset' I only see the parent cube added; or the child cylinder, if I mark that; or both as two separate primitives if I 'select hierarchy' first.

What do I need to do to my two primitive shapes so at they appear in the asset library as a single asset? Ideally while retaining the ability to refine them in the original blend file later.

Thanks.

Comment: It's currently not possible to add a collection of objects as a single asset, but you can try to join the geometries with CTRL J to have a single asset.

Comment: Just seen a duplicate question (once I had posted and could see the tag) ... the answer to which I did not understand but I will work at. 

How can I delete this question?

Comment: You don't need to delete it, you can close it by clicking on "Close" and choose duplicate and paste the link to the other question, it may guide other people when they're searching for the feature in the future :)